# Multi module android project inside a private maven repository

Tags: android, maven, artifactory

I have a multi module android project and currently anyone in our team can access the the modules from our private maven repository.

We are using `jFrog Artifactory` hosted in `aws` for managing the repositories. The structure of our project is something like this

`app
 -lib1
 -lib2
    -lib2a
    -lib2b`

I want to know if there is a way by which `lib2a` and `lib2b` is not accessible as separate modules but only accessible when someone adds the dependency of the parent module in their project which is `lib2` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way by which lib2a and lib2b is not accessible as separate modules but only accessible when someone adds the dependency of the parent module in their project which is lib2 in this case

**Short answer:**
**No**, you can't do it.

**Long answer:**
When you put an artifact in a maven repo you have the artifact files (may be an aar for your android libraries) and a pom file.

The pom file describes also the transitive dependencies of the artifact.
Currently you can't specify a parent dependency or a specific maven repo to be used (this one is under development).

It means that a build system, for example gradle, read the dependency, download from the repos the pom file and download all transitive dependencies.
When you download a transitive dependency there is no way to specify if you have just downloaded the parent or if you are directly downloading it.

It can be available, or not available without conditions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So the only way to achieve this behavoiur would be to merge the child modules into the parent, right ?

Comment: @sauvik It depens by your final goal. If you would like to limit the access, you can put these libs in another (authenticated) repo removing them from the transitive dependencies. Of course you have to organize the lib2 in different way.

Comment: if I put them in another repo, will there be a different set of authentication detail be in the lib2 ? Right now, the authentication details are in the main app

Comment: For each repo defined in the `repositories` block of the `build.gradle` you have to define the url and the credentials. Of course without credentials (or url) you won't be able to download the lib2a/b.

Comment: ok, got it. I will try putting the child modules in a separate repository. Thanks again for all the help.